# BIG QUERY IMPORT FROM CLOUD issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I have uploaded my data sets into google cloud. I am trying to import them into big query tables. I get an error declaring that the location of my data is not the "path" as declared in the google cloud browser= "55555/M04Q1%20Query.txt"

Thats my bucket and my file.... so something is missing-

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused by what your asking. The import path, if you're importing from a google cloud storage path should look like: "gs://bucket/object". Can you give more information about the request your are sending, how you are sending it, and the error you are getting?

Comment: Thats exactly it- I am using the online browser and I am trying to import data from Google cloud saved in a text file as: mo4q1%20Query.txt
its in a bucket called you123443-

please see below- cant figure out what I did wrong?
its publicly available data- nothing to hide...

Comment: Errors:
Unable to read source URI: gs://you123443/M04Q1%20Query.txt
Job ID: job_fd7e26c471f649168d29dd4ff9eb8082
Start Time: 7:25pm, 24 Mar 2013
End Time: 7:25pm, 24 Mar 2013
Destination Table: x8-micro-harmony-9:Aers.Q12004
Source URI: gs://you123443/M04Q1%20Query.txt
Source Format: CSV
Skip Leading Rows: 1
Max Bad Records: 100
Schema:
D_ISR_0112: INTEGER
D_0112: STRING
I_ISR_0112: INTEGER
I_0112: STRING
R_ISR_0112: INTEGER
R_0112: STRING

Comment: My guess, offhand, is that BigQuery is balking at the space in your file name. Can you rename the file something without a space and try again?

Comment: Never mind- I got it- The file needs to be saved as csv, not just comma deliminator... Thanks-!